# Only one third of image written in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

In this piece of code I'm trying to write values (`0.123` for this example) into the out image, which is a copy of the input image. But for some reason, only one third of the image is being written, while the other two thirds are still the copied input image, as you can see in the screenshot.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// image is of type CV_32FC3 and XYZ, values in range [0,1]
Mat out = Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());
image.copyTo(out);

for (int i = 0; i < out.rows; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < out.cols; j++)
  {
    out.at<float>(i,j) = 0.123;
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

PS: The bigger picture goal is a HDR image fusion into the out image, which actually works, but only for the left third of the out image, same as here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just setting the array to a scalar, you can use either

`out = Scalar(0.123, 0.123, 0.123);` or

`out.setTo(Scalar(0.123, 0.123, 0.123));`

It is a 3 channel image but you are accessing using float (which used to access pixels in a gray scale image), hence the 1/3rd.
Use Vec3f if you want to use for-loop to access the elements.

`out.at<cv::Vec3f>(i,j) = cv::Vec3f(0.123, 0.123, 0.123);`

You can access a particular channel's element by indexing.

```
out.at<cv::Vec3f>(j,i)[0] = 0.123;
out.at<cv::Vec3f>(j,i)[1] = 0.123;
out.at<cv::Vec3f>(j,i)[2] = 0.123;
```

Comment: Thank you both, I originally thought I didn't need `Vec3f`, because the way I did it without it, the HDR fusion actually worked for the left third, I was thinking it was some other error. I also might have tried `Vec3b` instead of `Vec3f`, not being aware of the other type.

Comment: probably you could change to for (int j = 0; j < 3*out.cols; j++)
  to process the whole image as if it had a single channel, but no idea why one should do that :D If your code isnt for testing you could remove all the loops and use .setTo function of Mat

Comment: Yeah. setTo is a better alternative for just setting Mat to a scalar. Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
out.at<float>(i,j) = 0.123;
```

to this:

```
out.at<cv::Vec3f>(i,j)[0] = 0.123;
out.at<cv::Vec3f>(i,j)[1] = 0.123;
out.at<cv::Vec3f>(i,j)[2] = 0.123;
```

because it's a color image, so it has 3 channels