# Why the imaging operation are performed upto the half (vertically) of the image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing very simple operation using opencv, but I could not understand why this bug/problem is occurring. The image is operated until the half of the image (vertically).

```
Mat img = imread("/Users/tanmoy/Documents/345.jpg");
Mat output = img.clone();

if( img.empty())
{
    cout << "File not available for reading"<<endl;
    return -1;
}

for(int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++){  
    for(int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++){ 

        if(img.at<uchar>(y,x) < 128)
            output.at<uchar>(y,x) = 0;
        else
            output.at<uchar>(y,x) = 256-1;

    }
}

imwrite("/Users/tanmoy/Documents/binary.jpg", output);
```

[image: The original image]
[image: The binary image]

It would be kind of you to look into this problem/issue. I could not figure it out.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379180/only-one-third-of-image-written-in-opencv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're working on a 3 channel image (loaded by default `imread`) as if it were a 1 channel image (you're accessing it with `.at<uchar>`).

Make sure to work on a grayscale image. Either:

1. Load it directly as grayscale:

   ```
   Mat img = imread("/Users/tanmoy/Documents/345.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
   Mat output = img.clone();
   ```
2. Convert to grayscale:

   ```
   Mat img = imread("/Users/tanmoy/Documents/345.jpg"); // Default loads a 3 channel image
   cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   Mat output = img.clone();
   ```

---

Please note that you can avoid the explicit `for` loop, either:

1. using [cv::threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html):

   ```
   Mat output;
   threshold(img, output, 128, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
   ```
2. using matrix binary operations:

   ```
   Mat output = img > 128;
   ```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer... Now I did it :)